# Swift, SSL Self Signed certificate IOS8+

Tags: swift, ssl, nsurlconnection

I want to implement the SSL in webservice call.
But having an error as below:

NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

### My code Below

```
func checkNetworkConnection(callback: ((isConnected: Bool) -> Void)!)
{
    var checkNetworkURL: String = “TESTURL”
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: checkNetworkURL)!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.timeoutInterval = 20000.0

    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)


        if error == nil{

            if data != nil{

                self.parser.getLoginResultDataDictionary(data!) {(dataDictionary) -> Void in
                    if let dataDict = dataDictionary[self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_RESULT] as? Dictionary<String,String>
                    {
                        if let status: AnyObject  = dataDict[self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_STATUS] {
                            if status as! String == self.constants.defaultsKeys.RESPONSE_SUCCESS {
                                callback(isConnected:  true)
                            }
                            else{
                                callback(isConnected:  false)
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            callback(isConnected:  false)
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        callback(isConnected:  false)
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                callback(isConnected:  false)
            }
        }
        else{
            callback(isConnected:  false)
        }
    //}
     }
```

### Method added

```
   public func connection(connection: NSURLConnection,  willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
{
    challenge.sender.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}
```

### Added Delegate as below

public class NetworkUtil : NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate {
}

How can i configure SSL in the above code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to implement [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html) method:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge)
{
    challenge.sender.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
    challenge.sender.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}
```

And if you are targeting older versions, you gonna need [canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:) method, which is deprecated since iOS8.

Comment: hris.to, doesnt work for me ...I am targeting to IOS 8.4

Comment: Could you please provide how did you try this? I use it all the time and didn't experience any issues so far.

Comment: hris.to , Did you get a chance to check. FYI i am using sendSynchronousRequest request.

Comment: You can't use certificate without making connection delegate. Please look at this tutorial how to implement connection via delegate methods http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift.